# How to open a NSAlert in awakeFromNib? (taking care of the window animation)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I get a problem with a NSAlert that is created in -awakeFromNib method.

The xib window animation takes some time, and the alert is crated and added to the app too early (so it is detached from the window).

If instead I delay the method call everything works fine, but I guess that's not the correct way to implement it. How should I code it instead?

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
       ...
      [self performSelector:@selector(showAlertMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the method is executed when the main thread is done with its current tasks you can dispatch the method call to the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self showAlertMethod];
});
```

Comment: @Patrick: all UI should be handled from main queue. So is the case here.

Comment: A little bit too late, but may I ask... **why** doesn't `awakeFromNib` run on the main queue? Isn't it supposed to be a configuration method (including, for example, colors)? Just happened to me that I initialized a view from a nib on a view controller (`viewDidLoad`) which supposedly runs on the main queue, perfect. I can configure it there. But if I subclass and override `awakeFromNib`, it won't update the UI, so I had to use GCD. I thought that, at least, `awakeFromNib` would run in the same queue as the object that instantiates it, but it doesn't. Weird.